# how to run an application in mac terminal without writing the extension name

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

So i am running an application and in the terminal i want to run the help screen i type:

```
   ./hashcat-cli64.app --help
```

is there a way to just type :

```
    hashcat --help
```

i want to get rid of the ./  and the .app at the end
as of right now i renamed it to hashcat but i have to run it like :

```
   ./hashcat.app --help
```

is this possible or do you always need to run with ./ to show the current directory?

Comment: Does `open -a hashcat-cli64 --args --help` do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chris's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3598119/chris-beck) method is the one I would use, but there is an alternative to use an alias.

In your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or whatever, add the line

```
alias hashcat="/path/to/hashcat.app"
```

You can even add parameters by this method

```
alias hchelp="/path/to/hashcat.app --help"
```

You can also create aliases on the bash command line.  It's trickier to do the same thing with the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you put something in your path, which is marked executable, then it may be found by the shell without using `./`.

So for instance, you could make a directory `~/bin` and add this to your path (perhaps by modifying your `.bashrc` file). Then, any links or scripts or programs or anything you put in your home directory subfolder `~/bin` could be run using the syntax you want.

I guess to answer your exact question what I would then do is run `ln -s path/to/hashcat/hashcat-cli64.app hashcat` inside of your `~/bin` directory after that.

(You could also easily do it by writing a bash script that calls hashcat, and forwards any arguments to it. And using `chmod +x` to mark the bash script executable.)

More info on making symlinks on OS X here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal